# How to group rows by either permutation of a two column composite key

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, group-by

Not sure the wording for the question is as clear as it should be (it's the best I could come up with) but here's an example to clear things up. I have a view, `Chats`, which is supposed to summarize the conversation history between two people. The view comprises of the following columns: `Sender`, `Recipient`, `Timestamp`, `LatestMessage` and `UnreadMessageCount`.

The `Chats` view's columns are all derived from a table, `Direct_Messages` which stores details about individual chat messages exchanged between users of the system. Here are its columns:
`ID`, `Sender`, `Recipient`, `Body`, `Timestamp`, `TimeRead` (is null if message hasn't been read by recipient). The view's `Timestamp` and `LatestMessage` columns have the values of the latest direct message between the two participants (latest by `Timestamp` FWIW).

The problem is really stemming from the fact that **only one permutation of the `Sender`, `Recipient` composite columns should exist in the `Chats` view** i.e. that of the latest exchange between the two participants. For example, if Gary sent a 'Hi' message to Barry, then Barry replied with 'Hello'--the only entry in `Chats` between these two guys should have the `Sender` as 'Barry', the `Recipient` as 'Gary', the `Timestamp` as the timestamp of Barry's reply, the `LatestMessage` as 'Hello' and the UnreadMessageCount as the number of messages the `Recipient` hasn't read.

I have tried to use `GROUP BY "Sender", "Recipient" OR "Recipient", "Sender"` but it just returns two columns: one grouped by Barry, Gary; and the other grouped by Gary, Barry

Here's my code:

```
SELECT Sender AS Sender,
       Recipient AS Recipient,
       Timestamp AS Timestamp,
       Body AS LatestMessage,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN TimeRead IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) AS UnreadMessageCount
FROM Direct_Messages
GROUP BY Sender, Recipient OR Recipient, Sender
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```

EDIT: Here's the sample data in the `Direct_Messages` table and the corresponding output in the `Chats` view

From `Direct_Messages`

```
ID          Sender  Recipient   Body    Timestamp                   TimeRead
148567984   Gary    Barry       Hi      2018-12-12 23:53:39.487     2018-12-12 23:55:45
1668701120  Barry   Gary        Hello   2018-12-12 23:54:49.326     NULL
```

Result in `Chats`:

```
Sender  Recipient   Timestamp                 LatestMessage UnreadMessageCount
Gary    Barry       2018-12-12 23:53:39.487   Hi            0
Barry   Gary        2018-12-12 23:54:49.326   Hello         1
```

Comment: That GROUP BY makes no sense at all... Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh Put in some edits

Comment: Don't you get the expected result if you skip the GROUP BY, and the SUM aggregation?

Comment: @jarlh No, thing is there are lots of `Sender` `Recipient` combinations in `Direct_Messages` e.g. Gary can be a `Sender` and Mary a `Recipient` in some other row  so I need to find a way to group the entries together which have the same `Sender` `Recipient` or `Recipient` `Sender` values. Then as for the SUM aggregation--I need it to be able to count the NULL `TimeRead`s i.e. to count the unread messages

Comment: Well, you could add some more rows of sample data to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get most of what you want by using `MIN()` and `MAX()` with multiple arguments.  With multiple arguments, these are *scalar* functions that operate like `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` in other databases:

```
SELECT MIN(Sender, Recipient) AS u1,
       MAX(Sender, Recipient) AS u2,
       MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp,
       -- Body AS LatestMessage,
       (COUNT(*) - COUNT(TimeRead)) as UnreadMessageCount
FROM Direct_Messages_cooked
GROUP BY u1, u2
ORDER BY MAX(Timestamp) DESC
```

The challenge is getting the latest method.  You can get this with conditional aggregation and an additional `JOIN`:

```
SELECT MIN(dmc.Sender, dmc.Recipient) AS u1,
       MAX(dmc.Sender, dmc.Recipient) AS u2,
       MAX(dmc.Timestamp) AS Timestamp,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dmc.Timestamp = dmc2.Timestamp THEN Body END) AS LatestMessage,
       (COUNT(*) - COUNT(dmc.TimeRead)) as UnreadMessageCount
FROM Direct_Messages_cooked dmc JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(Sender, Recipient) AS u1,
             MAX(Sender, Recipient) AS u2,
             MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp
      FROM Direct_Messages_cooked
      GROUP BY u1, u2
     ) dmc2
     ON dmc2.u1 = MIN(dmc.Sender, dmc.Recipient) AND
        dmc2.u2 = MAX(dmc.Sender, dmc.Recipient)
GROUP BY u1, u2
ORDER BY dmc2.Timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Will have to take a minute to take all that in before I can test it--then will get back at ya. Just one question, is the whole 'cooking' thing some sort of established practice for this kind of problem or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can 'pre-coock' your data in order to have always messages in same direction from every combination of users.

Sample, if your data is:

```
Sender Recipient
A ---> B
B ---> A
```

You change it to:

```
U1     U2
B ---> A (changed)
B ---> A
```

Like this:

```
SELECT (case when Sender > Recipient then Sender else Recipient end) AS u1,
       (case when Sender > Recipient then Recipient else Sender end) AS u2,
       Timestamp AS Timestamp,
       Body AS LatestMessage,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN TimeRead IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) AS UnreadMessageCount
FROM Direct_Messages_cooked
GROUP BY 
     (case when Sender > Recipient then Sender else Recipient end), 
     (case when Sender > Recipient then Recipient else Sender end) 
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```

*Notice: Be careful with performance ( I guess it is not important because you are tagged question as sqlite )*

You can use CTE to pre-coock your data and get a **more readable query**:

```
with Direct_Messages_coocked as
(
    select
      (case when Sender > Recipient then Sender else Recipient end) AS U1,
      (case when Sender > Recipient then Recipient else Sender end) AS U2,
      *
    from Direct_Messages
)
SELECT U1 AS U1,
       U2 AS U2,
       Timestamp AS Timestamp,
       Body AS LatestMessage,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN TimeRead IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) AS UnreadMessageCount
FROM Direct_Messages_coocked
GROUP BY U1, U2
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Will have to test it out and mentally digest the code, will feedback when that's done

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Gordon Linoff's and @dani herrera's insightful answers I managed to tweak about and come up with a succinct solution to my specific problem, though in the broader context of my initial question, @Gordon's answer seems, from my observation, to address the problem more fully. Here's what I managed to come up with:

```
SELECT Sender AS Sender,
       Recipient AS Recipient,
       Timestamp AS Timestamp,
       Body AS LatestMessage,
       (COUNT( * ) - COUNT(TimeRead) ) AS UnreadMessageCount
  FROM Direct_Messages
 GROUP BY (
              SELECT MAX(Sender, Recipient) 
          ),
          (
              SELECT MIN(Sender, Recipient) 
          )
 ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```